# Software com gravação em BD local e remoto

Tags: mysql, sql, python, banco-de-dados, projeto-de-software

Tenho uma dúvida da possibilidade de fazer um tipo de programa e quais meios usar. Só para deixar registrado, não estou pedindo "como fazer a programação", mas uma opinião de pessoas mais experientes sobre a possibilidade e viabilidade do projeto!!

**Funcionamento Desejado:** quero fazer um programa em janela para windows que seja instalável e trabalhe offline. Nesse programa vou cadastrar meus clientes e os serviços que prestarei a eles. Quando eu finalizar o registro o programa grava num BD local e também grava num BD online em algum servidor, no caso em um BD em MySQL.
Se for feita alguma alteração no registro no local, o programa verifica e registra também no online; o mesmo para exclusão.

**Motivo:** uso notebooks diversos em locais as vezes remotos e muitas vezes com conexão instável, porém tenho necessidade de registrar na hora os serviços prestados e preciso de uma cópia online para consulta do cliente.

Segue um exemplo ilustrativo do funcionamento do software na rede:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cadastro, edição, exclusão e sincronização também segue o caminho inverso. No caso poderia ter muito mais do que 2 PCs com o programa instalado, que poderiam fazer esses 4 processos simultaneamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O programa funcionaria de modo que o BD Local 1 estaria sempre em sincronia com o BD Local 2 e o BD Remoto.

Preciso saber se é possível e viável (facilidade e etc.), se alguém indica algum tipo de programação (pretendo estudá-la para criar o software), como funciona a integração BD local X online e quaisquer outras observações serão bem vindas.

Agradeço muito.

Comment: Removi partes do texto que não fazem jus à pergunta. Se tem alguma reclamação sobre o comportamento da comunidade você pode utilizar o [meta]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você for desenvolver apenas para Windows, você pode utilizar C# para construir o Software, ou java se quiser construir uma aplicação multiplataforma, existe também o Python que está em alta atualmente porém não posso opinar muito sobre o mesmo pois não o conheço bem, vou deixar aqui um link da IEEE onde você pode verificar o ranking das linguagens: https://spectrum.ieee.org/at-work/innovation/the-2018-top-programming-languages

Independente da linguagem que você for utilizar, aconselho você utilizar um Web Service para realizar a sincronização dos dados entre cliente e servidor, para que seu banco não fique de 'portas abertas para o mundo', uma vez que com o web service você possa definir quais pontos específicos deseja alterar, impossibilitando o acesso total a sua base de dados, você pode criar métodos de autenticação para seu web service também deixando-o ainda mais seguro. Com sua aplicação conectando diretamente em um banco remoto, isso pode deixar pontos de vulnerabilidade para que hackers consigam entrar em sua base. Com relação ao Mysql, tome cuidado para não infringir as suas licenças, ele é grátis apenas para o desenvolvimento, se você for instala-lo em um servidor e distribuir seu software comercialmente, você terá que comprar a sua licença de distribuição: https://www.mysql.com/products/

Aconselho você contratar uma hospedagem como da Locaweb, GoDaddy... entre outras, pois essas já possuem o Mysql instalado com as devidas licenças, caso você realmente for utilizar o Mysql.

Lembrando que você pode fazer um serviço windows em background para sincronizar os dados, pois uma vez que o usuário feche o sistema após a alteração, ele apenas irá sincronizar os dados ao abri-lo novamente.

Comment: Pois então, a questão da linguagem, realmente tem suas particularidades e preferências. A questão do WebService eu ainda não conheço (vou pesquisar mais)...você indica algum serviço referente a isso? Para um BD local qual serviço ou programa eu poderia usar? poderia ser direto no Access ou há outra alternativa? O BD remoto estou usando o MySQL da Hostinger, então não tenho problema. A distribuição é especifica de um cliente somente, com varios usuários. A sincronização quero que serja feita assim que o usuário clicar no botão 'OK!' é possível? o que significa "serviço windows em background"?

Comment: Outra coisa...é viável isso? já existe alguma plicação que funcione assim, pra servir de exemplo? se tiver algum link tb referente a isso, agradeço.

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho um exemplo concreto para você, os softwares que eu construí nesse estilo são todos de empresas privadas. Mas pesquise mais sobre essa tecnologias que citei, com certeza você vai achar bastantes informações que irão lhe ajudar.

Comment: Esse problema de sincronizar dados offline e online pode ser complicado. Veja por exemplo [essa discussão no Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Database/comments/38mvgu/sync_offline_database_with_online/). Pesquisar por algo como _offline database synchronization_ pode ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Sobre a possibilidade, **sim**, e não se trata de uma necessidade rara. Softwares que possuem recurso para continuar trabalhando *off-line* implementam recurso similar.

Sobre quais meios usar, existem vários e, apesar dos detalhes fornecidos, eles ainda permitem várias possibilidades. Para ilustrar segue uma opção não comentada nas respostas anteriores. Você pode empregar o padrão Command veja https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern que, de forma simplificada, reúne os detalhes (dados) de uma mudança (alteração) que foi aplicada no BD local. O objeto correspondente ao Command é sinalizado por meio de um evento para um serviço como [Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) (há solução similar para Azure, Google, ...). Ao receber tal evento (comando que reúne a mudança no seu BD local), quem o recebe teria a incumbência de aplicar a mudança em outro BD (o seu BD remoto). Nesta opção todas as alterações podem ser registradas em uma estratégia conhecida por [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)), que talvez seja relevante para o seu problema (apesar dos detalhes não é possível avaliar).